# Deleting entire columns and whitespace in .xml file

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Working with an xml file that contains excess whitespace and empty columns that I need to delete. So far, I've been able to delete specific node objects and/or elements of a node. I've been told previously that with xml files, you can't necessarily pinpoint or target whitespace in the file, but rather, you must replace it. How would I go about that?

Listed below is my code to remove either an entire node or a specific element within a node object. For example sake, let's assume we are using the following document:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file
I'm using elementtree, not panda or dom.

```
# To remove an entire node and all of its elements
# for country in root.findall('country'):
    # using root.findall() to avoid removal during traversal
    # description = country.find('description').text
    # if description == " Yurr ":
        # root.remove(country)

# To remove a specific element or node within 
# a node
for country in root.findall('country'):
    description_node = country.find('description')
    # This will remove the specific node 
    # 'description' in the .xml file. 
    if description_node.text == 'Liechtenstein has a lot of flowers.':
        country.remove(description_node)

tree.write('SampleData.xml')
```

Comment: Not sure what a column means in this context. That's not an XML term. If you supply a simple example input and output, I'm sure that would help clarify.

Comment: If you have `lxml`, this is a simple XSLT solution requiring no `for` loops or `if` logic!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0,

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="year"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

will strip all indentation whitespace and remove elements named `year`. Is that what you're after?